# Test if Item in OverflowMenu exists/not exists

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a OverFlowMenu in my Actionbar with several Items. The problem is that I added some items that the list is no longer fully visible which makes it not possible to test with `onView()` anymore.

Currently i am testing with the following lines of code:

```
onView(withText(R.string.thisString)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withText(R.string.thatString)).check(matches(doesNotExist()));
```

now i have a solution to to test explicit if an item at a certain position exists

```
onData(CoreMatchers.anything())
        .inAdapterView(CoreMatchers.<View>instanceOf(MenuPopupWindow.MenuDropDownListView.class))
        .atPosition(0)
        .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(R.string.thisString))));
```

which is not a perfect solution for me because i cannot verify that other items do not exist. and also makes the test not as dynamic as the previous implementation where i jsut were able to search if the item is displayed

Comment: `The problem is that I added some items that the list is no longer fully visible`. You can use [ViewMatchers#isDisplayingAtLeast(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers#isDisplayingAtLeast(int)) for partial views. I suggest this if you still want to use `onView`, as it's the one you should use for visual verification.

Comment: @Rakib Since some items are not visible at all this approach will not solve my problem i think. It is not that i want to use onView i just understand how it is working a little bit better.